# How to open aspx page like popup in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

When user clicks on linkButton it needs to open new window to display some data.
I try this:

```
string url = "~/SomePage.aspx";
                string cmd = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no' );";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", cmd, true);
```

But it doesn't work. I can't even manually navigate to this page. Opening new window work but it opens the same page in that new window.
So, how to display content from SomePage.aspx in this new window?

Comment: In dnn 6
use urlutils.popupurl.. see how login popup is opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot manually navigate to the page, then you are using the wrong URL.  View the page via the Admin | Pages feature to see what url it is using.  In code it is best to use the NavigateURL method to get the correct URL for a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
string url = "./SomePage.aspx";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock (Page, Page.GetType(), "openPopup", "window.open('" + url + "','_blank','height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no' );", True)
```

Comment: No, that does not work :( I always get url like this http://localhost/dnn/bla/blas/view_bla/tabid/121/language/en-US/SomePage.aspx in new window :(

Comment: You say you can't even navigate to the page manually? Is Somepage.aspx included in the root of your website?

Comment: No, not even manually. It's a dotnetnuke module. I added SomePage.aspx in it. But I can't navigate to any other page that already exists here :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about dotnetnuke. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit different from the exact solution, but have you tried something like this?

`<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">Microsoft</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have added an aspx page into a module the file path should be

/desktopmodules/modulefolder/something.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created page that I want like dnn page and open it like edit page from dnn in separate window.